# Limit memory usage of a java class

Tags: java, memory, jvm, cluster-analysis, moa

I am writing a java class which is to be run with a java MOA framework.
The class has functions to cluster a stream of points. This class is called by MOA application. I want to limit the total memory (at least the memory used on heap, can exclude stack memory) usage of this class (excluding the memory used by MOA application).

Is it possible? I hope its clear that the class is being instantiated and called by MOA application. I am running the MOA application first and then chosing to run myclass from GUI to perform the clustering. Because of this reason, the JVM options like -Xmx are not working for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can embed logic in the class to check Runtime.freeMemory() and Runtime.maxMemory() at intervals and take steps (flush caches, etc) when the limit seems to be close.  A little "iffy" since different platforms report heap stats differently.

You can also use a SoftReference scheme for some of your "optional" storage.  Then GC will delete objects if it needs the heap.  (Though this scheme is using a sledgehammer to swat a mosquito.)

And you can, of course, simply count your object allocations.

Comment: You might not have enough freeMemory() because you need to run a GC. It can seem a little close but you can be a long way from running out of memory.

Comment: Yeah, there's the rub with Java.  Depending on the GC algorithm and how the stats are reported you may seem to be out of memory, and it's only necessary to run GC and you have loads of free memory.  I think the JVM is supposed to run GC before reporting a freeMemory() value, but you don't know if that's a major GC or a minor one or what, and the JVM may even bypass that GC (like many ignore "runGC" calls) for "efficiency" reasons.

Comment: Thanx!! Counting the object allocations is what is the last resort. I will try out your other suggestions and see if they are working for me.f

Answer (score 0):

You can only limit memory usage global for a JVM.

To limit the usage of a class, you need to start another JVM and use that class in the new JVM.

However, it usually best to fix your code so the class never uses too much memory. ;)

Comment: Its not about fixing the code. The memory usage will increase with the no of points clustered so far, and also vary according to the choice of a few parameters. I want to limit the total memory usage so that the program tells me when it is about to exceed the memory limit.

Comment: You can count the number of points/objects created assuming you know their size and ensure that doesn't exceed some number.